# Objective c method that accepts types id and double?

Tags: objective-c

I have a method that has to be able to accept `double` and `id` types.

I can't just wrap the double in an `NSNumber` wrapper because of backwards compatibility.
How would I define my method to accept both double and id ?

```
- (void) addBothDoublesAndIds: (id, double) doubleOrObject;
```

So above in parenthesis are just what I would *like* to accept, the syntax is just for demonstration.

Comment: I'm confused.. are you saying you want one single method that accepts either an `id` or a `double`?

Comment: double or object ? why not two separate methods ? also, I can't understand why you can't use `NSNumber`, since it is an object that can wrap `double`s..

Comment: How is this for backwards compatibility as the method can't have taken  the option before?

Answer (score 2):

In short, you can't.   Arguments must be of only one type.   What Justin suggests is one solution, or you could define two methods.

Effectively, every selector -- every method name -- should have the same argumentation across all declarations and implementations.   There are some places where this rule is broken in the various frameworks, and it causes pain.

Answer (score 2):

In many cases, you're asking for trouble by accepting `id` too.

Write two methods, and have one wrap the other.

```
- (void) addDouble: (double) aDouble {
[self addNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:aDouble]];
}

- (void) addNumber: (NSNumber *) aNumber {
// do stuff with your number
}
```

The runtime will send your message to the correct one, and you have saner type checking to boot.

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
- (void)addDouble:(double)aDouble andObject:(id)anObject;
```

if it's supposed to be either-or (can't quite tell from the OP), then consider separate methods, or the method above with some means to distinguish whether the parameter to use is the `double` or the `id` (e.g. if the `anObject` is `nil`, the `double` value will be used).

normally, you'd stick with "single parameter+multiple methods" in this case. An object which holds the info may be another (clearer) solution for this.